# Write something over an image html

Tags: html

How I write a text into a photo?

```
<a href="/"><img src"photo.png" />TEXT</a>
```

I have to do with css position absolute and relative? I know it works with position absolute and relative but it is another way to do and how is the best way? If is the only way with position absolute and relative, position relative must be the main photo and position absolute the content(TEXT) ?

Comment: similar question asked too many times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do like this

```
<img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/5a/SMirC-hi.svg" /><div style="position:relative; left:120px;top:-150px">TEXT</div>
```

for demo

> http://jsfiddle.net/5CSej/

Answer (score 0):

try something like this,but this is with absolute and relative

```
<tr>
<div class="image">
  <img alt="" src="http://www.YourDomain.com/img/yourImage.jpg" />
  <div class="text">
    <p>This is some demonstration text</p>
    <p>This is some more wonderful text</p>
  </div>
</div>
</tr>
```

ur css

```
.image {
    position:relative;
}
.image .text {
    position:absolute;
    top:10px;
    left:10px;
    width:300px;
}
```

This will place text directly on an image

Comment: What if the OP wants the image and text to be clickable?

Comment: no problem, pass <a href=""> to image,this can be noted,same will be done with text...try it once.

Answer (score 0):

okay, here is another method to add a text over the image..the condition is you have to use a background image. Here is the **[Demo](http://jsbin.com/kimawigi/1/)**.

```
div:before{
  content: "";
  position:absolute; 
  background:url('http://lorempixel.com/400/400') no-repeat;
  width:400px; height:400px;
  z-index:-1;
}

<div><h1>Look at ME!</h1></div>
```

Comment: @John Smith do you like this method to put the text over image?